# Is it possible to create color patterns for many objects created from an array?

Tags: modifiers, color

This is the amusement ride "The Zipper" I'm trying to create in blender:

[image]

I am working on the lights around the ring here:

[image]

I created one light and used a few array modifiers to create this:

[image]

MY PROBLEM: I am unable to create the color pattern from the reference image.
I want the lights to be red on the outside and change to yellow and orange around the center.

I searched online everywhere, but couldn't find an answer to this.
Perhaps it isn't possible?
I want to avoid applying the array modifiers to keep my model simple, but that might be the only way.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can use *Gradient Texture* with an empty to control the center.

1. Use *Texture Coordinate > Object*
2. Put an empty where you want the center, and use it as target for *Texture Coordinate*
3. Use *Gradient Texture > Spherical* and Color Ramp

[image]

Comment: wow that's it ah ah

Comment: Funny thing, I tried Wave texture at first, but couldn't make it work :).

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This was so simple and helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Someone must know how to do it with the *Gradient* node but it was much easier for me to use the *Texture > Wave node (Rings* mode).

You just need to plug *Texture Coordinate* (*Object* output) *> Mapping > Wave > ColorRamp > Diffuse > Material Output*. Tweak some values like *Wave*'s *Scale* or *Mapping*'s *Location* and *Scale* so that it fits the objects.

You can even animate the lights if you keyframes these values.

[image]

Comment: So even though this isn't the solution I used, it is VERY COOL! I will definitely be using this node chain in the lights for the front of the ride! It will look so cool when I animate it!! Thanks for much!!

Comment: Nice answer. Can it be made so that each object instance has a single color instead of the gradient showing through?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe with animation nodes?